# Using a table as a variable in a function

Tags: function-construction, list-manipulation

I have a bunch of arrays and need to extract specific rows and columns of these that obey certain criteria. So for one table I'd do like this

```
func[x_]=Cases[table,{n_,__}/;a[x]<n<b[x]]
```

where b[x] and a[x] are numeric functions of a real number that I defined earlier. How can I do this so that func takes also a table as an argument?
I've tried

```
func[table_?MatrixQ,x_]
func[table_?(MatrixQ[#,NumericQ]&),x_]
```

but they give me the same error

```
Array::argbu : Array called with 1 argument; between 2 and 4 arguments are expected
```

If it helps, the tables have only 2 columns (but the number of rows varies)

Comment: you need to be using `SetDelayed` ..  `:=`  (otherwise your pattern syntax looks correct)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It is `n_` in the program, I somehow deleted it when pasting it here

Comment: Please post minimal, but full, version of code that gives such error. Shown error is reported by [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) function, which is not used in posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've just made a syntax error by leaving out `&&` between the two inequality operators.  If I understand your question, you should have functions defined as follows:

```
ClearAll[a, b, func];
a[x_Real] :=(* example calc *)-1*x;
b[x_Real] :=(* example calc *)x;
func[table_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &), x_] := 
    Cases[table, {n_, __} /; a[x] < n && b[x] > n];
```

...with an example in this case of a simple filtering operation on a matrix shown as follows:

First, let's create some data. This creates a real-valued matrix:

```
temp = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}];
```

To work with the same data, here's what I see:

```
temp = {{-0.19773, -0.403283, -0.203482, 
0.560051, -0.662339}, {-0.229652, -0.382093, -0.369309, 0.576484, 
0.566491}, {0.30776, 0.471342, 0.556337, 0.997326, 
0.749479}, {0.951397, 0.256563, 
0.740539, -0.9422, -0.552236}, {0.937068, 0.903586, -0.0219966, 
0.917632, 0.0494045}};
```

Now call `func` on the `temp` variable with some real value in place of `x` as follows:

```
func[temp, .3]
```

...which returns

```
{{-0.19773, -0.403283, -0.203482, 
0.560051, -0.662339}, {-0.229652, -0.382093, -0.369309, 0.576484, 
0.566491}}
```

You can see that `func` "filtered" the rows using the functions `a` and `b` (I'm just using your function names here for comparability sake) as well as the pattern variable `n`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked. Just one question though: why does using my syntax works when the table is not a variable?

Comment: @bernie, in the documentation for `Less`, for example, it indicates that the function does some simplification when its arguments are not numbers.  That could be the cause.  Are you sure you used `SetDelayed` so that your function is exactly: `func[table_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &), x_] := 
 Cases[table, {n_, __} /; a[x] < n < b[x]]`?  I was able to get this syntax to work actually so you weren't far off if at all.

Comment: The problem was the `SetDelayed` part, that I was forgetting. Thanks for the help!